# Trying to figure out how to return the mean value of each column in a data frame using a list

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame which shows the average life expectancy of a country from 1800 to 2018.The Columns are labeled like this: XYear. For example: X2000. I made a function which returns the mean value of a selected column. Here's the part I'm struggling with: the assignment is asking me to create a list which has the mean value of every column in the data frame, using the aforementioned function.

I tried making a list element which would select all rows and columns except for the first ones (selecting them with [-1,-1]).

```
life_exp <- read.csv("data/life_expectancy_years.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Write a function `get_col_mean()` that takes in a column name and a data frame and returns the mean of that column. Make sure to properly handle NA values

```
get_col_mean <- function(col_name, data_frame_name) {
return(mean(data_frame_name[, col_name], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Create a list `col_means` that has the mean value of each column in the data frame (except the `Country` column). You should use your function above.

I tried this:
column_means = get_col_mean(life_exp$life_exp[, -1], life_exp)

But I got this error message:

> In mean.default(data_frame_name[, col_name], na.rm = TRUE) :
>     argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: As @Peter_Evan said, try get_col_mean("life_exp", life_exp)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing the `$` operator. This is used to grab a single column by name.

```
#data frame
z <- data.frame(l = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(4,3,2,3), c =c(1,'',3,4)))

z$l
[1] 1 2 3 4

z$z
NULL

#numeric (note that I am providing the column name as a string
get_col_mean("l", z)

#outout
[1] 3

#this is the same as putting NULL in
get_col_mean(z$z, z)

#your presumed error
[1] NA
Warning message:
  In mean.default(data_frame_name[, col_name], na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If you are looking to apply this to each column, a for loop or the `apply` family of functions is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That was very helpful. I used lapply and it worked.